# Generating elements of a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Say, I'm given **a** group of quanterions $Q_{10}$ under multiplication whose set of elements $\left \{ i,j,k,x,y \right \}$ and I'm asked to generate the elements of the subgroup of $Q_{10}$, say, for the element x.

How I think this should be done is finding out what elements are generated by z:
$\left \langle z \right \rangle=\left \{ z^{1},z^{2},\cdot \cdot \cdot  \right \}$ up to where $z^{i}=z^{j}$ where the order of the element z is finite.

Am I right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the definition of $ Q_{10}$?